# How to create a list of strings that contains the same value expect for the number at the end?

Tags: python, python-2.7

So, what I am essentially trying to do is find a quicker way to do the following:

```
vars = ['var1', 'var2', 'var3', 'var4', 'var5']
```

Where the beginning of the string will always be var but the number changes at the end. Is there a quicker and easier way to do this?

Comment: Why are you doing this? You almost certainly have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248627).

Comment: So this list will be new column names in a pandas dataframe. I am trying to figure out if there is an easier way of doing this instead of typing each value out in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
vars = [f'var{x}' for x in range(1,6)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
['var{}'.format(i) for i in range(1, 6)]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're renaming columns:

Note: this is renaming all columns in a pandas df with three columns:

```
vars = [f'var{x}' for x in range(1,4)]
df.columns = vars

df.head()

  var1      var2        var3
0    A  20020215  20190217.0
1    B  20010219         NaN
2    C  20150217  20180315.0
3    D  20100216         NaN
4    E  19870412  20191118.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
var_list = list(“{}{}”.format(“var”, k) for k in range(1,6))
```